# wiremock is throwing Nullpointer when trying from the mvn clean install but working fine with eclipse JunitTest

Tags: java, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am using the following wiremock dependency :

com.github.tomakehurst
wiremock-standalone
test
2.6.0

and when running from eclipse by choosing run as JunitTest everything is working fine. But when I am running this program from maven I am getting the following error.

```
wiremock.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping["request"]->com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.RequestPattern["bodyPatterns"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
at com.example.integration.controller.FileUploadControllerIntegrationTest.configureSystemUnderTest(FileUploadControllerIntegrationTest.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.integration.controller.FileUploadControllerIntegrationTest.configureSystemUnderTest(FileUploadControllerIntegrationTest.java:47)
```

I am having following code which is throwing error.

```java
package com.example.integration.controller;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import static com.example.integration.controller.TestConstants.*;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.ConsoleNotifier;
import com.example.Application;

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@import(TestConfig.class)
@testinstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class FileUploadControllerIntegrationTest extends GenericIntegrationTest {
@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

private WireMockServer wireMockServer;

@BeforeAll
void configureSystemUnderTest() {
    this.wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(8090).notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)));
    this.wireMockServer.start();
}

@AfterAll
void stopWireMockServer() {
    this.wireMockServer.stop();
}

@DisplayName("upload and validate with success")
@Test
public void testUploadFile() throws Exception {
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(createRequest(BCM_DEPLOY_SCOPE, "integration-payload/order-type.json"))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();
    assertNotNull(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
}

@DisplayName("upload and validate with validation failed.")
@Test
public void uploadFileWithValidationFail() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(createRequest(BCM_DEPLOY_SCOPE, "integration-payload/order-type-with-invalid.json"))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(content().json(populateJsonToString("__files/json/validation-failure-response.json")));

}

/**
 * @param endpoint
 * @param multipartFile
 * @param headers
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws JSONException
 */
private MockHttpServletRequestBuilder createRequest(String scope, String payloadFile)
        throws IOException, JSONException {
    String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/files/upload";

    InputStream fis = new ClassPathResource(payloadFile).getInputStream();
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", fis);
    HttpHeaders headers = getHeadersUsingScope(scope);
    return multipart(endpoint).file(multipartFile).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).headers(headers);
}
}
```

And this is the mapping file payload I am using.

```
{ 
   "request":{ 
      "method":"POST",
      "headers":{ 
         "Authorization":{ 
            "contains":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhel9hdHRyIjp7ImFwcGxpY2F0aW9uX25hbWUiOiJSZWdTZXJ2aWNlIiwiYXBwbGljYXRpb25faWQiOiJCQ1MifSwiemlkIjoic2FwLWljYnMiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoidGVzdFVzZXIiLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJ1c2VyIG5hbWUiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJ1YWEtc2VydmljZS1iY3MuQnVzQ29uZmlnbk1hbmFnZUNvbnRlbnQiXSwiZXhwIjoyMTQ3NDgzNjQ3LCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJzYi1CQ1NTZXJ2aWNlIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0VXNlckB0ZXN0T3JnIiwiY2lkIjoic2ItQkNTU2VydmljZSJ9.ax5hEOLjmazyXKak9GHnQ3ZswQbL2rkRv2fM6p5rD3NPeUKPO6IaXTImGNCwk3wk6UbkTXuQu8rOQzHugvMLajYwFTpeMuOMjCZ-B8MgrNZq2EKiKe6aQKfzZ6vJZkPWon2UuZWNfKFxbBtglcVi4rL4Z655IWu4zWJ9_r6ruHVybW8eU4hD-4UNdJB2m4pISJw1usqA-_GaMMfQ5j6azx93m1qHuWUYMMmTtq_JefHiA4FueYHh4cBj-aHvTa_PYkG8rg0qY6dvJPw1R9ANKNG5CsQZmzUsY3a9KZX5wgRoSYshePj25mR1GmOzb8PCIDUmyWST-_keF0OnnqJhyQ"
         },
         "Content-Type":{ 
            "contains":"application/json"
         },
         "Accept-Language":{ 
            "contains":"en"
         }
      },
      "url":"/busconfig/validate",
      "bodyPatterns":[ 
         { 
            "equalToJson":{                
               "serviceEntities":{ 
                  "OrderType":{ 
                     "data":[ 
                        { 
                           "Code":"TE",
                           "BusConfignIsDeleted":false,
                           "BusConfignValidStart":"/Date(1571356800000)/",
                           "BusConfignValidEnd":"/Date(1571356800000)/"
                        },
                        { 
                           "Code":"YZ",
                           "BusConfignIsDeleted":false,
                           "BusConfignValidStart":"/Date(1572739200000)/",
                           "BusConfignValidEnd":"/Date(1575072000000)/"
                        }
                     ],
                     "entityEndPoint":"SalesOrderOrderTypeService/OrderType"
                  },
                  "OrderTypeText":{ 
                     "data":[ 
                        { 
                           "Code":"TE",
                           "BusConfignIsDeleted":false,
                           "LanguageCode":"en",
                           "LanguageName":"English",
                           "Description":"TE Desc"
                        },
                        { 
                           "Code":"YZ",
                           "BusConfignIsDeleted":false,
                           "LanguageCode":"en",
                           "Description":"Validation error code"
                        }
                     ],
                     "dependency":[ 
                        "OrderType"
                     ],
                     "entityEndPoint":"SalesOrderOrderTypeService/OrderTypeText"
                  }
               },
               "required":[ 
                  "OrderType",
                  "OrderTypeText"
               ],
               "description":"Check",
               "changeType":"m"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "response":{ 
      "status":200
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.6.0 is ancient.

Try 2.25.1, and use the jre8 JAR unless you're on Java 7.